# round to nearest multiple of 5 in a range in php

Tags: php, if-statement, get, integer, rounding

I have this if statement:

```
if($_GET["angle_1"] > 39) {
    $markers["###ANGLE###"] = "45"; 
} elseif($_GET["angle_1"] > 29 && $_GET["angle_1"] < 40) { 
    $markers["###ANGLE###"] = "35"; 
} elseif($_GET["angle_1"] < 30) {
     $markers["###ANGLE###"] = "25"; 
} else { 
     $markers["###ANGLE###"] = "45"; 
}
```

Is there a better / simpler way to do this check, f.x. with round that will round the integer to the nearest 5, i.e. 28 -> 25 or 34 -> 35 etc. and in that, if the integer is less than 25, it will always be 25 and if the integer is higher than 45, it will always be 45 and again if the integer is between 30 and 40 it will always be 35.

That returned value will be used to display an image.

EDIT:

I have 3 images: image_25, image_35 and image_45, therefore the need to round.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133893/1726343

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let say `$x` has the number:

```
$x = 39;
```

If you want the closest multiple of 5 (39 --> 40):

```
$x = round($x / 5) * 5;
```

If you want to round up (36 --> 40):

```
$x = ceil($x / 5) * 5;
```

If you want to round down (39 --> 35):

```
$x = floor($x / 5) * 5;
```

After defining `$x`, you can use the following to make sure its in the 25-45 range:

```
$x = ($x > 45) ? 45 : ($x < 25) ? 25 : $x;
```

Comment: This works almost as it should, but if X is 48 the returned value will be 50, but if X is 48 I need the returned value to be 45, X cannot be less than 25 and higher than 45

Comment: Then why don't you add a statement for this particular case for yourself?

Comment: Add the following: `$x = ($x > 45) ? 45 : ($x < 25) ? 25 : $x;`

Comment: Arh.. thanks.. This I can work with! :) Answer accepted! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
$var = 5 * round($n / 5);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913353/round-integer-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-in-php)