# PHP Rounding up to specific set of numbers

Tags: php

I want to round up any given number to the nearest set of specific values only. The values are 5,10,20,25,50,100

So if the given number is 2 it will be rounding up to 5. If it's 71.6 it will be rounding down to 50, if it's 250 it will be rounding down to 100

Anybody can give me a clue how to do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Didnt this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913353/round-integer-to-nearest-multiple-of-5-in-php answer your question.. or you simply didnt search before posting..!

Comment: Hi, ofcourse I did a search before. But I don't want it to be rounding up to multiple of five. I just want it to be rounding up to specific numbers.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific then, including an example. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @zoora You did? The most common... :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147356/find-closest-number-in-an-array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have improved the question thanks

Comment: Have a look at the two links above, provided by kAlmAcetA. Those look promising.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA my bad I was looking for different keyword :( thanks for the direction. it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

use a loop:

```
$numbers = array(5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100);
$result = $input;
foreach ($numbers as $n) {
    if ($input < $n) {
        $result = $n;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: incorrect results (for example any number under 50)

Comment: Fixed. I'm not sure why I thought I had to reverse the array.

Comment: Thanks @barmar, but the input is always rounding up. If the given input is 13 the output will be 20 instead of 10

Comment: That's what you said in the question: _I want to round **up** any given number_

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here : [Find number which is greater than or equal to N in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147356/find-closest-number-in-an-array). Thanks to @kAlmAcetA

```
function closest($array, $number) {

    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a >= $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array) // or return NULL;
}
```